# How to make function input become a string, if it's not?

Tags: python, string, function, input, python-2.7

So basically, let's say you define a function and then write something in () brackets after then function. If I write function(gay), it ends up as 'error name not defined' Python2.73

```
def lenRecur(aStr):
    '''
    aStr: a string

    returns: int, the length of aStr
    '''
    print type(aStr)
    return

def lenRecur2(aStr):
    '''
    aStr: a string

    returns: int, the length of aStr
    '''
    s = str(aStr)
    print type(s)
    return
```

So when I type lenRecur(gay) or lenRecur2(gay), it ends up as an error whatever I do. So is there a way to avoid it? Without using "" quote marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - unless your input is already a variable that holds a string (or another object).

However, you could use a `try-except` block (but it won't actually do anything if there's an error).

```
try:
    lenRecur(foo)
    lenRecur2(foo)
except NameError:
    pass
```

Comment: I don't think even a try/except block would work. In the example he's passing in what the Python compiler will always consider a variable. The error's likely a NameError which would mean it's not even making it into the function.

Comment: @SuperFamousGuy what do you mean? the `except` block will catch any `NameError` the interpreter throws at it (inside the `try` block of course) - this is no exception (no pun intended).

Comment: Ah! It appears I can't read too well... I'm sure you've caught on but I was under the impression you were try/except'ing the content of the methods, not running the methods themselves.

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs before the function even gets called. Python tries to evaluate the arguments before calling the function. So, Python encounters the bare name `gay` and wonders, "What the hell is that?"
When it fails to find its value in the local, enclosing, global or builtin scopes, it raises a NameError.

There is no way around this. You must clearly specify what you mean. If `gay` is a string, you must use quotes.